# проектирование базы данных mySQL

Tags: sql

Подскажите по проектированию БД. Есть таблица продукты (id, name, amount) и заготовки (к примеру, бульон, каша, пюре), с аналогичными атрибутами. Заготовки состоят из продуктов. Сделал три таблицы заготовки, продукты и продукты_заготовки. Зачем? Клиент нажимает на кнопку заготовки и видит из каких продуктов она состоит (такой функционал). Для выборки использую два INNER JOIN (продукты_заготовки, продукты) в одном SELECT.

Главный сказал убрать две таблицы и в продукты внести поле заготовки, чтобы не плодить таблицы.

У меня вопрос: нарушают ли данные изменения нормализацию формы. Я считаю, что продукты и заготовки разные сущности. И как тогда в случае реализации одной таблицы получить заготовки? Мне нужен FK на саму таблицу? Помогите разобраться или покажите путь.

Comment: *У меня вопрос: нарушают ли данные изменения нормализацию формы.* Начальный вариант - да. затребованный руководителем - скорее всего нет, надо смотреть реализацию. *Я считаю, что продукты и заготовки разные сущности.* Эммм... вы вообще анализ предметной области делали?

Comment: *заготовки (к примеру, бульон, каша, пюре)* Угу... а потом соединяем две заготовки (бульон и зажарка), получая новую заготовку (суповая основа) - что, ещё таблицу будешь делать?

Comment: Представь, да! Называется блюдо_композиция. Куда FK входит блюдо, продукты и заготовки. Но не в этом вопрос.

Comment: Ответ искусственного интеллекта: Ваш первоначальный подход с тремя таблицами (продукты, заготовки, продукты_заготовки) соответствует нормализации данных и хорошо подходит для представления связи "многие ко многим" между продуктами и заготовками. Он позволяет легко хранить информацию о том, из каких продуктов состоят заготовки и какие заготовки включают определенный продукт.

Comment: Если вы удалите таблицы заготовок и продукты_заготовки, и добавите поле "заготовки" в таблицу продуктов, это будет нарушать нормализацию данных. Поле заготовки в таблице продуктов будет представлять собой повторяющуюся группу и нарушит принцип первой нормальной формы.

Comment: Ну и что? получаешь обычное дерево. Parent-Child. У папки-блюда - куча детей-продуктов и заготовок, у заготовок - свои детки-продукты.. нормальная схема. А кивать на искусственный интеллект, знаешь ли... лучше всё же своим пользоваться.

Comment: @Akina Но для связи детей с родителями придётся же всё-таки дополнительную таблицу делать? Так то да, вполне можно и нужно и блюда и продукты и полуфабрикаты в одной таблице хранить.

Comment: @CrazyElf Само собой, тут же не одно дерево, а лес-сетка. M:N. Но каждое конечное блюдо - это дерево.

Comment: `и в продукты внести поле заготовки` продукт соль, может входить в любую из заготовок. Как это _главный_ планирует реализовать в одной таблице? У вас же реляционная БД, а не носкл, куда можно джсоны пихать